# peoplesoft schedule query to external server

Tags: peoplesoft

Is it possible in peoplesoft to schedule a query daily and transfer the result file (for example in xls) to a server or to a local drive ? In other words to extract the result out of the peoplesoft application itself? I don't mean to transfer it by mail...

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible.  You can create the query as a PSQUERY and then schedule the query.

See [Scheduling Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E38689_01/pt853pbr0/eng/pt/tpsq/task_SchedulingQueries-c0753f.html) for more details

The summary is:

1. Create a query in PSQUERY
2. Schedule Query (Reporting Tools->Query->Schedule Query)
3. Select your runcontrol
4. Select your query (from #1) and enter parameters
5. Press Run
6. Change the type to File
7. Change the Format if needed (XLS is an option)
8. Enter the folder path in the output destination
9. Select a recurrence
10. Press OK

The output destination is from the point of view of the Process scheduler so c:\temp\ would put the files on the local drive of the process scheduler, not your PC.  If the process scheduler has the correct permissions (and it's running on windows) you can put a UNC in here or in linux, you can mount the location you need and save it there.